# call a javascript function on button with hashtag

Tags: javascript, html, button

im not familiar with javascript but i want to load a function on a button click.

in the head i've got the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'formData'     : {
            'timestamp' : '1349865153',
            'token'     : 'ac534e1229656a7817ab0f20f9933c23',
            'pid'     : '<?=$idProject?>'
        },
        'swf'      : '<?=base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<?=base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'buttonText' : 'Bestand upload',
        'onUploadComplete': function() {location.reload(true)}
    }); 
</script>
```

but how do i call the javascript with a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here what you have on the head is jQuery code.

If you want to use the same jQuery code to achieve this instead of javascript, you can use below code.

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Click"/>
```

jQuery code

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'formData'     : {
            'timestamp' : '1349865153',
            'token'     : 'ac534e1229656a7817ab0f20f9933c23',
            'pid'     : '<?=$idProject?>'
        },
        'swf'      : '<?=base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<?=base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'buttonText' : 'Bestand upload',
        'onUploadComplete': function() {location.reload(true)}
       });
   });
```

To get the jQuery work in code you need to include any version of the jQuery.js file in your page.. also you need to put the above jQuery code inside ready function , which is the jQuery document loading call.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, just have

```
$("#ID").click(function() {
    alert("hello");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myButtonId');
btn.onclick = function(){
  console.log('do this');
}
```

Obviously replace #myButtonId with whatever the ID is of your button and console.log with whatever code you want to run when the button is clicked.

Comment: this won't work in javascript as you include the #myButtonId, instead of myButtonId

Comment: @TijoKVarghese Good catch. Sorry it's late.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div id="buttonSomeID">Click</div>

$("#buttonSomeID").click(function(){
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'formData'     : {
            'timestamp' : '1349865153',
            'token'     : 'ac534e1229656a7817ab0f20f9933c23',
            'pid'     : '<?=$idProject?>'
        },
        'swf'      : '<?=base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<?=base_url();?>uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'buttonText' : 'Bestand upload',
        'onUploadComplete': function() {location.reload(true)}
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zuhce)

Answer (score 0):

use the `on` method provided by [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#mybtn").on("click", function() {
  //your code goes here
});
```